# Conversion from Beamer Presentation (Slides) to Beamer Poster

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

How can I easily and "safely" convert my Beamer presentation (slides) to an elegant Beamer poster like the following?:

[image]

[Slides wanting to convert.](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/56d4e3d8140dca670ff049c0/output/output.pdf?cache_bust=1456806638501&compileGroup=standard&build=153307132ff)

(Question not the same as this: [Is it possible to convert a beamer presentation directly to an a0 Poster?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78041/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-beamer-presentation-directly-to-an-a0-poster))

Answer (score 1):

A poster is a different way of organizing information compared to a slide show, so there is no easy conversion. You need to rethink your layout, illustrations, and wording (imho your beamer presentation has far too much text, by the way).

That said, the template you picked (Jacobs Landscape Poster, http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster) is rather straightforward to use - just insert your own code into the template. A beamer frame becomes a poster block, and that's about it. Minimal non-working example:

```
\title{Categorification of Higman's Lemma\\Admits Applicability and Constructive Proof} % Poster title
\author{Julian Rachman} % Author(s)
\institute{West High School} % Institution(s)
[...]
\begin{alertblock}{Abstract}
Higman's Lemma, a special case of Kruskal's Tree Theorem, provides fascinating results in the areas of combinatorics, logic, and theoretical computer science. [...]
\end{alertblock}
\begin{block}{Introduction}
Higman's Lemma is concerned with the preservation of well-quasi-orderedness over the construction of ordered algebraic structures. It was first introduced by Higman in his main theorem concerned with abstract algebras equipped with quasi-orders and later became an important statement in combinatorics and theoretical computer science where it was narrowed down to the following concise theorem:
\end{block}
\begin{theorem}[Highman's Lemma]
If $\leqslant$ is a \textit{wqo} on $A$, then $\preccurlyeq$ is a \textit{wqo} on $A^*$.
\end{theorem}
[...]
```

Result:
[image: poster title]
[image: poster body]

For future questions, please try first if you can find a solution yourself, and if you encounter problems, post them as a question (e.g., 'I tried to put a theorem on my poster, this is the code, the result is such, but I would like it to be different').